# Why json.dumps() on a DataFrame doesn't work?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import json
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{"a":[]}, {"a":[]}])
>>> df["a"]=df.apply(lambda x: json.dumps(x['a']), axis=1)
>>> df
    a
0  []
1  []
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{"a":[]}, {"a":[]}])
>>> df.to_csv('tmp.csv', index=False)
>>> df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv')
>>> df["a"]=df.apply(lambda x: json.dumps(x['a']), axis=1)
>>> df
      a
0  "[]"
1  "[]"
>>>
```

For the first method, `json.dumps()` doesn't work, column `a` doesn't contain string values. However, if I write `df` to file and read it back and apply the method, then column `a` contains string values.

Why is that?

**------- Update -------**

Firstly, thank you guys, for the answers. Based on the answers so far, it looks like it's because pandas didn't print column `a` with quotes properly, but column `a` still has string values. This makes sense.

However, if we dump these two data frames to files. The two files would have different content as the below.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import json
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{"a":[]}, {"a":[]}])
>>> df["a"]=df.apply(lambda x: json.dumps(x['a']), axis=1)
>>> df.to_csv("a.csv")
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{"a":[]}, {"a":[]}])
>>> df.to_csv('tmp.csv', index=False)
>>> df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv')
>>> df["a"]=df.apply(lambda x: json.dumps(x['a']), axis=1)
>>> df.to_csv("b.csv")
>>> 
>>> def read_file(filename: str):
...     with open(filename, 'r') as f:
...         for line in f.readlines():
...             print(line, end="")
... 
>>> 
>>> read_file('a.csv')
,a
0,[]
1,[]
>>> read_file('b.csv')
,a
0,"""[]"""
1,"""[]"""
```

If it's only a format issue of printing, and values in both data frames are strings, then why the dumped files are different?

Comment: Column `a` does contain string values in the first test. When pandas prints a dataframe, it doesn't put quotes around strings.

Comment: Try `type(df.loc[0]['a'])`

Answer (score 2):

You are being fooled by the formatting.  The column in your first example HAS been converted to a string.  pandas doesn't print the quote marks like Python does, because you usually don't see them.

```
>>> df['b'] = df.apply(lambda x: json.dumps(x['a']),axis=1)
>>> df
    a   b
0  []  []
1  []  []
>>> df['a']
0    []
1    []
Name: a, dtype: object
>>> df['b']
0    []
1    []
Name: b, dtype: object
>>> df.iloc[0,0]
[]
>>> df.iloc[0,1]
'[]'
>>>
```

As Gaberocksall correctly points out, your export-then-import example shows the quotes because what you read from the CSV was a string, not a list.  So, the value is actually `'"[]"'`.

Comment: Note that the second output _does_ contain quote marks because that's how `json.dumps()` serializes strings - it puts quotes around them. So in the dataframe it literally contains the string `'"[]"'`.